# Why Android Developer Bundle Tool Does not Recognize the Key In my Keystore?

Tags: android, android-app-signing, bundletool

I have an entry in my keystore file. I can see the contents with the command:

```sh
$ keytool -list -keystore app-signing-key.keystore
Enter keystore password:  
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

appsigning, Sep 8, 2021, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): D:....<the sha1 here>...:D
```

I am trying to use this entry to create apks using the java bundle tool and the following command, but I am getting an error that the entry cannot be found.

```sh
$ java -jar $HOME/bin/bundletool-all-1.8.0.jar build-apks --bundle ./app-release.aab --output app.apks --connected-device --ks ./app-signing-key.keystore --ks-key-alias=appsigning
Enter keystore password: 
[BT:1.8.0] Error: No key found with alias 'appsigning' in keystore.
com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.exceptions.CommandExecutionException: No key found with alias 'appsigning' in keystore.
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.exceptions.InternalExceptionBuilder.build(InternalExceptionBuilder.java:57)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.SignerConfig.readSigningConfigFromLoadedKeyStore(SignerConfig.java:184)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.SignerConfig.extractFromKeystore(SignerConfig.java:140)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.BuildApksCommand.populateSigningConfigurationFromFlags(BuildApksCommand.java:1127)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.BuildApksCommand.fromFlags(BuildApksCommand.java:599)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.commands.BuildApksCommand.fromFlags(BuildApksCommand.java:565)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.BundleToolMain.main(BundleToolMain.java:77)
        at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.BundleToolMain.main(BundleToolMain.java:49)
```

which is weird.

Why the bundletool does not see the entry using the alias name?

Comment: If you can reproduce the bug with a non-sensitive keystore, I would recommend to file a bug in bundletool GitHub's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide alias for your keystore
Like:

```
keytool -list -keystore app-signing-key.keystore -alias KEY_ALIAS_HERE
```

If you dont specify any `KEY_ALIAS` then it will take default alias as 'appsigning'.